# Input Number set max value to decimal

Tags: html, validation, html-input

How to set html input type number, max value such that the max value is less than boundary (max) value not equal to boundary value? Now what I can the do is as following but thats not the right solution because the list will go on

`<input type="number" min="0" max="24" />`

How to can I accept any value between 0 - 24 not 0 or 24

`<input type="number" min="0" max="23.9">`

or

`<input type="number" min="0" max="23.99">`

or

`<input type="number" min="0" max="23.999">`

or

`<input type="number" min="0" max="23.999">`

or

`<input type="number" min="0" max="23.9999">`

I need to accept floating values, options other than regex

Comment: idk the answer, but you can write your own validation when someone submits the data. Check each input value and make sure it's within the right range. This way you can allow the range to be to 24 and then use your validation

Comment: Have you tried giving it a `step="0.01"`? [Number input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)

Comment: `step="0.01"` is for the slider to set next value it does nothing more than that

Comment: @duxfox-- can't do custom validation, is there a way to do with simple form validations? I can't use 3rd party libs

Comment: @Jackboys yea just grab the value out of the input and do a basic check for `> 0 and < 24` - no need for third party libs, but it seems like taplar found the solution below?

Comment: @Taplar I can use jquery code
`      $("#myForm").validate({
        messages: {
          abc: {
            max: "Please enter a number less than 24"
          }
        }
      });
    })`

Answer (score 2):

You can give the input a step to define the increments.

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="23.99" step="0.01">
```

Answer (score 0):

input number should not allow number to type more than the maximum value please check my below  code it will help you for sure.

```js
$("[type='number']").keypress(function (evt) {
console.log(evt.key); 

 var regex = /[0-9]/;
  if(regex.test(evt.key) ) {
    let value = parseInt($("[type='number']").val()+evt.key);
    console.log("value",value);
    value <= 24 ? "" : evt.preventDefault();
    }
    else
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" min="0" max="24" step="0.01">
```